# UIBarButtonItem to open new view when using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, uiview, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I need to create the `UIToolbar` and the `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically. I'm using `Storyboard` for the layout.
How is now a new view opened by pressing the toolbar button which was programmatically created? (I know how to do it with `Segue` when the button is created in the Interface Builder but I can't use this approach here).

Comment: What kind of presentation do you want? Modal? Push?

Comment: I would use the modal presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create the `UIBarButtonItem` using the following code :

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(showNewView)];
```

Then,

```
-(void)showNewView
{
  UIStoryboard *story =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *newViewController = [[postDetailViewControllerIphone alloc]init];
  newViewController=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newView"];
  [self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

This code will allow the barButtonItem to open the new view controller.

If u haven't added barButtonItem to the toolbar then do this after creating barButtonItem.

```
NSArray *toolBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonItem,nil];
[self.toolBar setItems:bottomtoolBarItems];
```

This will add your barButtonItem to the toolbar.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer. One more questions. I already have a set of views in my storyboard. The new view needs to get generated programmatically (as your code proposed)out of an existing view (viewcontroller). How do I proceed from that. The view is generated during runtime but not part of the Storyboard as far as I understand. Do I need to draw a new view in the storyboard and call it (its classes) `"newView"` without using a Segue?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your `UIBarButtonItem` make sure you set the target and action. Then in the called method, present your next view controller.

Create the bar button item.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(presentVC:)];
```

Present the view controller.

```
-(void)presentVC:(id)sender
{
    [self presentViewController: otherViewController animated: YES completion:^{
        // COMPLETION BLOCK
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does it mean I can actually mix both approaches in storyboard: using segues and using code to connect views (viewcontrollers)?